# Getting started with Twitter on iOS

Tags: objective-c, api, twitter

For the past 4 hours I've been trying to learn how to get Twitter to work with Cocoa and Obj-C. I've read tons of tutorials and followed through just to be stumped by something not working in the end or just no compiling, or later learning that its outdated because Twitter now uses OAuth or something.

The closest I came is following this tutorial twice 
http://www.mobiledevmag.com/2010/10/how-to-build-your-twitter-engine-library-for-iphone/#figure7
and nothing was displayed at the end.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on using, or even just setting up, Twitter APIs? I've used FB APIs successfully.

Specifically for the app I'm working on, I need users to be able to post tweets and follow other users.

Any resources/tutorials would be appreciated. I've already looked at the libraries on Twitter, I'm just completely stumped on how to use them -_-

Comment: Sharekit is a free, easy way, to integrate Twitter into your application. http://www.getsharekit.com/ Their source code may also help in constructing your own twitter engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) but it is specific to Twitter only.

Comment: I was trying to use this, but the tutorial on the github page wasn't very clear

Comment: I had problems with the MGTwitterEngine recently, some OAuth problem about an oauth_verifier param not valid(any more?).

Comment: Yeah that was my main problem. I think they changed the entire authentication system. I registered an app and its giving me like 2 keys, a secret, and authorization URLs that have to be linked into the app

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is too high level but I really like [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/). It's open source and it supports many services. I found the source code very readable and nicely structured, so learning by what they did is easy.

You can authenticate and send tweets with just a few lines. The Sharekit twitter client supports OAuth via webview and XAuth.

Using it is very easy to share Text it's only:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];
[SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
```

after setting up your Twitter data in the SHKConfig.h like

```
#define TWITTER_KEY @"123234"
#define TWITTER_SECRET @"123234"

#define SHKTwitterConsumerKey       @"444"
#define SHKTwitterSecret            @"5555"
#define SHKTwitterCallbackUrl       @"http://example.com" // You need to set this if using
```

OAuth, see note above (xAuth users can skip it)

Comment: I'm looking at this right now. A little confusing. Being completely new with twitter, this might sound dumb, but where do I put the..consumer key? Or whichever keys link it to the app on Twitter

Comment: @Chris, Updated my answer. I've never used such an easy to use library.

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I'm looking for, but a great start to actually get my feet wet. APIs can be such a bitch